# Unable to restore from mysql database dump

Tags: mysql

I have made a dump of my database in which one table is pretty huge (about 4 million records) and has good number of indices(One full text index along with a primary key and 3 unique indices). When i try to restore this dump the restore hangs(its been running for five days now) when it tries to execute the statement which enables keys (ALTER table x ENABLE keys).

Any suggestions on how to go about restoring this dump are more than welcome. The table in 
question is a myisam table.

Here is the output of showprocesslist

```
mysql> show processlist;
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Id   | User     | Host                                            | db            | Command | Time | State                | Info                                           |
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| 2350 | rdsadmin | localhost:52508                                 | NULL          | Sleep   | 3701 |                      | NULL                                           |
| 3331 | root     | <remote_ip>                            | <db> | Query   | 7971 | Repair with keycache | /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `entities` ENABLE KEYS */ |
| 3810 | root     | <remote_ip> | NULL          | Query   |    0 | NULL                 | show processlist                               |
+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Where is the ALTER statement located - after the data, or after the CREATE statement?

Comment: Any of your filesystems full ? e.g. /tmp

Comment: Alter table is located after the data and there is a loads of empty disk space !!!

Thanks.

Comment: What's the current state of the alter table statement? Run "Show processlist;" and update your question with the results.

Comment: Thanks. That statement has been running for about 2 hours, which is a lot different than 5 days. But the state (Repair with keycache) gives us a clue to the problem. "Repair by sorting" is typically faster. Check the size of your max sort file, it might need to be increased:

show variables like 'myisam_max_sort_file_size';

Comment: Thanks Walker... I am going to try that.. The statement runs for 2 hours because it terminated the 5 days one and executed the import again... But now i am on to trying that configuration variable.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is so slow is that the alter table is using "Repair with keycache" to build the index.  This builds the index by adding one entry at a time into the index.

The much faster way is to use "Repair with sort".  However, MySQL needs to have lots of memory and temporary disk space to make this work, and what will usually happen is that MySQL will start by using the "sort" method, run out of space, and fall back to the "keycache" method.

The way around that is to allow your MySQL server to use more space for sorting.  This is controlled by some server variables:

- [myisam_max_sort_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_max_sort_file_size) - set this to as big a value as you can safely afford - eg. 150G
- [myisam_sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_sort_buffer_size) - again, big is better - eg. 1G

These are both dynamic variables, but I doubt that changing them once the alter table has started will have much benefit.  If you don't want to alter your system config, then an alternative approach is to build the indexes using myisamchk in repair mode, allocating large sort buffers.

Comment: oops - I had not noticed Ike's comment. My answer is virtually a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not support "alter table x enable keys" statement:

```
alter table a enable keys;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "keys"
LINE 1: alter table a enable keys;
                             ^
```

Try to dump your MySQL database with `mysqldump --compatible=postgresql` - maybe it will load just fine then.

You can also try to dump and import only schema first with `mysqldump --compatible=postresql --no-data`. It would be easier to correct any incompatibilities in dump file by hand. If successfully imported then dump and import data only with `mysqldump --compatible=postresql --no-create-info`.